# Image gallery for ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, webforms

Does anyone have a suggestions for a superb cool image gallery that I can use for a website I am creating?

Comment: You should list out some requirements.  Do you want ASP.NET proper, or do you want ASP.NET MVC, ASP.NET with AJAX control toolkit.  Does it need to be free?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm assuming that by "superb cool" you're going to want a slick, "web 2", responsive client-side interface.

I would suggest you use a javascript library such as jQuery, and look for an image gallery plugin for it.  There are a ton of them out there, for example: http://speckyboy.com/2009/06/03/15-amazing-jquery-image-galleryslideshow-plugins-and-tutorials/

Answer (score 2):

You might look at the silverlight examples at http://www.silverlight.net/community/samples/silverlight-samples/

Answer (score 1):

http://cutesoft.net/ASP.NET+Image+Gallery/

We use this one. You can modify many functions by changing the js, css and template files.

Answer (score 1):

[Gallery Server Pro](http://www.galleryserverpro.com/) is an ASP.NET open source digital asset management and web gallery application. It is built as a single user control you can drop into your existing application.

Disclaimer: I am its creator and lead developer.

Answer (score 0):

To display they nicely on the page you can use jQuery FancyBox.

http://fancybox.net/home